# Subfield generated by 2 subfields

Tags: field-theory, definition, extension-field

Let $F/K$ be a field extension and $L_1,L_2$ be subfields of $F$ containing $K$.

There is a notation I don't know what it's called, it's $L_1L_2$, defined by the subfield generated by $L_1   \cup  L_2$. So can anyone give me the name?

Furthermore, do we have an explicit describe for this notation? I mean suppose $L_1,L_2$ are vector spaces over K with finitely dimensions, can we find the basis of $L_1L_2$ or something like that? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's called the compositum of the two field extensions. if $ L_1/K $ and $ L_2/K $ are both finite, then $ L_1 L_2 / K $ in a larger field $ F $ is spanned by elements of the form $ \alpha_i \beta_j $, where $ \alpha_i $ is a basis for $ L_1/K $ and $ \beta_j $ is a basis for $ L_2/K $. These elements may fail to be linearly independent, so they need not form a basis for $ L_1 L_2/K $, but one may always compute a basis by using row reduction over $ K $ upon writing the $ \alpha_i \beta_j $ in a chosen basis for $ F/K $.

Comment: Can you explain why the spanning set of $L_1L_2$ has the form like that?

Comment: I mean this is a subfield, and to generate a subfield is pretty complicated

Comment: @chítrungchâu The finite $ K $-linear combinations of the products of the form $ l_1 l_2 $, where $ l_1 \in L_1 $ and $ l_2 \in L_2 $ forms a subfield of $ F $, and it is clearly the smallest subfield containing both $ L_1 $ and $ L_2 $. (The only non-obvious thing to note is the existence of multiplicative inverses, but this is resolved since the inverse of an algebraic number is a polynomial function of that algebraic number.) Now, the spanning set should be obvious.